# How does the child components property change without any communication between child and parent component?

Tags: angular

How does the child components property change without any communication between child and parent component? 
As a magic, the child components property is manipulated,  without  parent to child communication.Can someone explain me how does this happen?
Please have a look at the code here, 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ucQ47vTBSOyBv8jr1qEp?p=preview
I update the form controls value with,

```
SetFormByPatchValue()  {
    this.formGroup.patchValue();
}
```

The above code will manipulate the properties of the child component.

**Example:2**
Here is a link to another [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7cl86rW2oFDcpCc4XDBc?p=preview). You can see that i have added another date component, whose value do not change on edit.

Comment: Do you mean how can it sync the values in component and markup? If so, then Angular runs a change detection whenever data changes and it updates all the references while also updating the markup.